# What CPU architecture was first to implement 'inverted borrow' carry flag during subtractions?

Tags: history, programming, cpu, cpu-flag-bits

### Background

In two's complement arithmetics, if one wants to calculate a subtraction having only an adder that calculates

`{cout,result}=full_adder(arg1,arg2,cin)`,

where `cin` and `cout` are incoming and outgoing carries, respectively, the way is to invert the second argument (a subtrahend) and to add extra one to the sum:

`a-b = a + (~b) + 1`

Using the `full_adder()` as defined above, that would be:

`{some_cout,result}=full_adder(a,~b,1)`

The `some_cout` is inverted borrow here: it is one when there were no borrow in ordinary subtraction of `b` from `a` and vice versa.

Next, that extra one could be actually an incoming borrow, which is also inverted: when it is one, a normal subtraction takes place, when it is zero, the result is 1 less:

`{inv_borrowout,result}=full_adder(a,~b,inv_borrowin)`

For those familiar with 6502 that is readily recognizable as the exact way the SBC instruction there works.

In more "conventional" architectures like 68000, Z80 or x86, the carries in subtraction are true borrows, that is, they get inverted before and after the addition with the inverted second argument. Extra inversion usually costs some logic, die space and worse timings.

### Question

The one known member of 'inverted carries' architecture is 6502, the second known to me is ARM.

What CPU architecture was the first to optimize carries during subtraction by leaving them inverted? Were there any other adopters of such approach besides 6502 and ARM?

Comment: From recollection, the 6801 also has the inverted carry. I'd guess the 6502 inherited it from there, and the ARM inherited it from the 6502.

Comment: I would expect that the first machines with carry propagation would have performed two's-complement subtraction by adding the ones' complement of the subtrahend along with an extra carry, and the inverting of the flag to represent "borrow" was a later innovation.

Comment: Please use tags to define the scope of a question.  Although you used 6502 and ARM as examples, they are unlikely to be the correct answer to the question ("Which was the *first*"), so they they do not belong as tags to the question.

Comment: Inverting is not free, but inverting a single bit is pretty cheap.  In fact, modern designs often double invert in order to amplify for long wire runs.

Comment: @OmarL I'm failing to confirm that 6801 has inverted carry. According to this http://bitsavers.org/components/motorola/6801/MC6801RM_AD2_MC6801_Reference_Manual_May84.pdf its carry is not inverted.

Comment: @ErikEidt If the ALU has to perform both addition and subtraction, now we have not simply an extra invertor or two, but two XOR gates (to invert or not to invert carries) and extra logic just to generate control signal to those XOR gates.

Answer (score 4):

The PDP-8, like a number of other architectures, doesn't have subtraction.  Thus, subtraction is necessarily done by negation followed by addition.

The PDP-8 does have a carry bit (called the link bit).  On addition, a carry out of the high bit of accumulator will *complement* the link bit, so you have to set it to a known value to interpret it.  The negation operation is formed by one's complement of accumulator and increment in one instruction — and the link can be initialized to 0 or 1 in the same negation instruction, if desired.  The increment part will then complement the link if there's a carry out (which there will be for negative numbers, i.e. positive numbers complemented).

Comment: You might also reference the PDP-5 which has a similar architecture, and came earlier.  The PDP-4 represents a kind of transition between ones complement arithmetic and twos complement.

Comment: I would question that L could be treated as carry here at all -- either inverted or not, complementing on true carryout or not. The reason is that it would be two different operations there, adding inverted subtrahend and then incrementing accumulator. Thus there's no meaningful carry for subtraction.

Comment: @lvd, the negation operation (complementing & incrementing) on a PDP-8 would normally happen first, then second, addition (of negated operand) with the other operand.  So, I suppose one could check the link bit after the negation to verify that didn't overflow, and then, proceed with addition, checking the link bit again afterwards.

Comment: See [this answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/arithmetic-operations-on-multiple-words-on-the-pdp-8/2305#2305) for the code for triple-precision C = A-B.

Comment: No subtraction? The [Manchester 'Baby'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_Baby) had **only** subtraction (no addition).  Coupled with 'load accumulator negated', it got by.